# AWS CLI: Get parent user details after sts-assume-role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to automate some tagging with Ansible playbooks. One of the things I want to accomplish is tagging a resource with a username of the person who created it. The issue is the sts-assume-role obfuscates the user data of the top-level account.

```
# cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
aws_access_key_id = JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ

[childaccount]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/child-acct-admin
source_profile = default

# aws iam get-user
{
    "User": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::4567891230:user/someuser",
        "UserName": "someuser",
        "UserId": "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2018-01-04T15:21:51Z",
        "PasswordLastUsed": "2019-01-11T15:24:32Z"
    }
}

# aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-my-user-profile
{
    "UserProfile": {
        "IamUserArn": "arn:aws:iam::4567891230:user/someuser",
        "Name": "someuser",
        "SshUsername": "someuser"
    }
}

# export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=childaccount
# aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-my-user-profile
{
    "UserProfile": {
        "SshUsername": "child-acct-admin-botocore-sess",
        "Name": "child-acct-admin/botocore-session-123456789",
        "IamUserArn": "arn:aws:sts::234567898:assumed-role/child-acct-admin/botocore-session-123456789"
    }
}

# aws iam get-user

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetUser operation: Must specify userName when calling with non-User credentials
```

I need some command I can execute to give me the top-level account details. The only avenue I can think of is to parse the credentials file and try and use the assumed-role name to map back to the profile loaded, and the parent profile. Then pass the keys directly of the top-level account (in this example, default) to give the actual username. It's a lot more involved than it should be.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to get the "source role" but you might be able to do this with an "external id"

Comment: Found this article on it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the long way. This approach assumes that the credentials and child account role are defined in your ~/.aws/credentials file. Written in Ansible.

```
- name: Query AWS role loaded
  shell: aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-my-user-profile --query 'UserProfile.Name' | awk -F'["/]' '{print $2}'
  register: role_in_use

- name: Discover AWS profile loaded
  shell: awk '/\[/{prefix=$0; next} $1{print prefix $0}' ~/.aws/credentials | grep role/{{ role_in_use.stdout }} | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
  register: profile_in_use

- name: Find AWS source profile
  shell: awk '/\[/{prefix=$0; next} $1{print prefix $0}' ~/.aws/credentials| grep "\[{{ profile_in_use.stdout }}\]source_profile =" | awk '{print $3}'
  register: src_profile

- name: Set AWS source user
  shell: aws opsworks --region us-east-1 describe-my-user-profile --query 'UserProfile.Name' --profile {{ src_profile.stdout }} | awk -F'["/]' '{print $2}'
  register: src_user
```

From there, you can reference the username ala: {{ src_user.stdout }}